# Helping figuring out H1 CSS inheritance

Tags: css

I have a Sharepoint site that is using a custom CSS file (say, custom.css) and applied it to the site's Master Page. I'm trying to modify the "Heading 1" style in the RTE to remove the bold and created a custom definition for the class .ms-rteElement-H1. This works across the site, except for on Web Part pages.

I can't understand why my custom definition is being overridden by one from the "Theme" stylesheet.

**In the `<head>`:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/company/accesstesting/_catalogs/theme/Themed/9262B884/search-7E1AFF02.css?ctag=0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/company/accesstesting/_catalogs/theme/Themed/9262B884/corev4-8A0ABD2F.css?ctag=0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/company/accesstesting/Style%20Library/Access%20Testing%20Custom%20Stylesheets/custom.css"/>
```

**In the `<body>`:**

```
<div style="" allowdelete="false" class="ms-WPBody" width="100%" id="WebPartWPQ3" haspers="false" webpartid="xxxx">
    <h1 class="ms-rteElement-H1">My Heading</h1>
    etc.
</div>
```

**Result:**
Firebug inspector is saying that it is taking `font-weight:bold` from `.ms-WPBody h1` definition in `corev4-8A0ABD2F.css`

Maybe my understanding of CSS inheritance is wrong, but I can't think why that would take precedence over the inline class?

Comment: OK, I found the reason for the problem - CSS specificity:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Now I just need to figure out how to get around it...

Comment: It is done now. Apologies for the slow response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the reason for the problem - CSS specificity: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

In your "custom.css" create this entry .ms-rteElement-H1 h1 { //your stuff for your custom h1... }
Notice the h1 after your ms-rteElement-H1 class name. This CSS selector will now have a higher specificity than the default one, .ms-WPBody h1 { // ms default... }
As it refers to the h1 elements under the .ms-rteElement-H1 class.

Hope this helps.

Edit:
Sorry should have checked what you did. the selector .ms-rteElement-H1 h1 will not apply to your h1 element. This selector specifies that the CSS will apply to all h1 descendants of the element that has the .ms-rteElement-H1 class. Modified example below would work. Given that you have a .ms-rteElement-H1 h1 { // your properties... } class defined.

```
    <div style="" allowdelete="false" class="ms-WPBody" width="100%" id="WebPartWPQ3" haspers="false" webpartid="xxxx">
    <div class="ms-rteElement-H1">
      <h1>My Heading</h1>
    </div>
    etc.
</div>
```

of course you can make it much cleaner and nicer, this is just an example of how you can solve it.

Comment: Thanks, but the heading style is provided by the Master Page and I don't want to muck around with it.

I did noticed thought, that in the Sharepoint default htmleditorstyles.css it defines `H1.ms-rteElement-H1` as well as just `.ms-rteElement-H1`. Putting my custom styles into the former works for sure, because it increases the specificity, but I don't know why that element is broken down that way and hope it doesn't result in any bugs... (can't imagine it would though, since there shouldn't be any other h1??)

Comment: You could also overwrite .ms-WPBody h1 {} in your custom.css file. Then it would only affect pages where you include your custom CSS. No functionality should be affected by you updating text style from bold to non bold.